# Нужна помощь в решении задачи

Tags: javascript

Собственно выполняю задание на Codewars([Ссылка](https://www.codewars.com/kata/vector-class/train/javascript)) и столкнулся с проблемой:
что при тестировании кода, не всё хорошо...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Описание
Здесь описаны методы: для Сложения(add), вычитания(subtract), умножения(Dot), и возведения в квадрат(norm)
пример с Codewars:

```
var a = new Vector([1,2,3]);
var b = new Vector([3,4,5]);
var c = new Vector([5,6,7,8]);
a.add(b); // should return Vector([4,6,8])
a.subtract(b); // should return Vector([-2,-2,-2])
a.dot(b); // should return 1*3+2*4+3*5 = 26
a.norm(); // should return sqrt(1^2+2^2+3^2)=sqrt(14)
a.add(c); // throws an error
```

```js
function Vector(arr) {
   this.arr = arr;
}

Vector.prototype = {

    add: function(v){
            if(this.arr.length != v.length){
                throw new Error('Size mismatch');
            }
            var add_res = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++){
                add_res.push(this.arr[i] +v[i]);
            }
            return add_res;
    },

    subtract: function(v){
            if(this.arr.length != v.length){
                throw new Error('Size mismatch');
            }
            var subtract_res = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++){
                subtract_res.push(this.arr[i] - v[i]);
            }
            return subtract_res;
    },

    dot: function(v){
        if(this.arr.length != v.length){
                throw new Error('Size mismatch');
            }
            var dot_res = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++){
                dot_res += (this.arr[i] *= v[i]);
            }
            return dot_res;
    },

    norm: function(v){
        var res = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++){
            res += Math.pow(this.arr[i], 2);
        }   
        return Math.sqrt(res);     
    },
    equals: function(v){
        if(this.toString() == v.toString()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    toString: function () {
        return '(' + this.arr.join(',') + ')';
    },
}
```

при проверке ругается на функцию **checkSize**. Объясните где я допустил ошибку?)

Comment: а что должен делать код?

Comment: `subtract_res.push(this.arr[i] * v[i]);` ?? звездочка - это не вычитание

Comment: да моя опечатка, спасибо.  @ Grundy поправил описание.

Comment: как по твоему, что за аргумент `v` вот тут `v.length`? какого типа?

Comment: как я думаю, это должен быть массив.

Comment: Почему массив? если даже в примере вызова в задаче передается Vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Параметром методов ожидается другой `Vector`, а у него нет свойства `length`, как и доступа к элементам массива через индексер.

```
Vector.prototype = {

  size: function() {
    return this.arr.length;
  },

  component: function(index) {
    return this.arr[index];
  },

  add: function(v) {
    if (this.size() != v.size()) {
      throw new Error('Size mismatch');
    }
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
        result.push(this.arr[i] + v.component(i));
    }
    return new Vector(result);
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! сам бы я не додумался) но теперь возьму на заметку ваше решение!